# show information from database based on dates mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that contains information and has columns 'Date Start' and 'Date End'

I'm wondering if there is a way to show data from the database between those dates.

So for example let's say i schedule something on the 1st december and then it ends on the 3rd. This is my current query

```
<?
$query2 = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM `Announcements` " );
$announecment = mysql_fetch_object ( $query2 ) ;

<div class="page-bg"  style="background-image: url('<?echo $announecment->backgroundim;?>');"></div>
<?}?>
```

Comment: Sure there is and there are too many ways to go about this. Have you researched this and tried something? Anything at all. Plus, the schema/values/column types are unknown.

Comment: "announecment" - Btw, the word as an FYI is "announcement" ;-)

Comment: Yeah I found a few things but it seems to be based on dates set out of the database?

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: *"Yeah I found a few things but it seems to be based on dates set out of the database?"* - Isn't that what the question is about?

Comment: @Fred-ii- hahahaha thanks! Will change that now :P

Comment: yeah, it helps and especially when you're looking for something related when debugging or others who may have control over the code.

Comment: so... you've been given an answer below, did you try that?

Comment: Yeah have just tried, and commented back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide the names for the columns, I'm going to use `date_start` and `date_end` to represent them, but you need to use the actual column names.

The query you are looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Announcements` WHERE `date_start` < NOW() AND `date_end` > NOW();
```

This is under the assumption that those timestamps are set by the database. If they are set within the application logic and the timezones do not match, this may still give you issues. In that case, instead of using `NOW()`, you will want to use the php `date` function to generate a date, and pass that in in place of using the MySQL `NOW()` construct.

---

You also will want to use [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), as mentioned in the comments on your original question to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried this and the date / time is set in the database, not via the application. For some reason though it's not showing any results.

I've set the startdate as 2017-11-14 08:00:00 and the enddate as 2017-11-29 21:00:00.

Not returning anything though

Comment: I had the greater than/less than mixed up, edited, try the above again.

Comment: I actually had it right to begin with, and for some derpy reason edited it to be wrong, leading to the issue mentioned in my last comment. Probably has something to do with not having my coffee yet.